# Adding gcc compiler to Poky image for raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, boot, cross-compilation, gcc, yocto

I am using raspberry Pi 3 running a poky image built using the Yocto project.
Is there any possible solution to add gcc compiler to the image? 
I found the cross-compilation very complicated and unfeasible for me (No possible ssh or wired connection between my laptop and the raspberry).

I tried adding features under `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` in the local.conf file like  `tools-sdk`and `tools-debugs` as a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593794/cross-compile-gcc-and-gdb-with-yocto)  but the new image doesn't boot.

**Question**

Is there a solution to add gcc to the poky image or to poky?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have an image made in the /tmp folder.You need to delete the /tmp folder and run the bitbake again in order to create a new image.